# HTML5/CSS - div stretching greater than body 100%

Tags: css, html, layout

I am trying to lay out a web application and running into problems with divs stretching outside of body and html.

http://jsfiddle.net/dex3703/Pftpu/

The pink inner div extends outside of its container when set to 100% height. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `#header` has a height of 55px.
- `#topnav` has a height of 65px.
- `#mainsection` has a height of 90%.
- `#drawer` has a height of 50px.

You're trying to assert that `55px + 65px + 90% + 50px = 100%`, but you can't do that.  It will be true for some height (where the height of your whole content is 1700px, see below), but not all heights:

```
55px + 65px + 90% + 50px = 100%
55px + 65px + 50px       = 10%
170px                    = 10%
1700px                   = 100%
```

---

**EDIT:** You can achieve what you want by using relative/absolute positions appropriately.  See the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pftpu/12/

Note that this will still be greater than 100% because of the borders around the entirety of the page.  You can wrap them in another div, but I wanted to show this example by only changing the CSS properties relevant to the main issue you were having.

Comment: What layout would you suggest so that the headers and footers are fixed height in the correct position and #mainsection fills the rest of the space?

Comment: Please see my edit above, regarding absolute and relative CSS positions (and the attached [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pftpu/12/) example).

Comment: Isn't absolute going to overlap with other contents?

Comment: It will not overlap with other contents if you position the elements correctly.  The top two sections and the bottom section are of fixed size, so if the elements are properly positioned, then no overlapping will occur.  The middle section is expandable; this is achieved by setting the `top` and `bottom` properties for that section (and notably *not* the `height` property).  Think of it as follows: the way he defines how his middle section should expand is that it will *always* start 125px from the top and end 50px from the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had something to do with position attributes but I hadn't quite gotten theren. The border is just for my benefit to see what's going on. Can't I set box-sizing to content-box so the border is drawn inside, and that will eliminate the scrollbar?

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis Your method is like this one-- stevesanderson.github.com/fixed-height-layouts-demo/simple.html. I thought I was working from this but hadn't quite apparently. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing pixels and percentages, that'll never work.

`#mainsection` has 90%, leaving 10% for `#header` (65px), `#topnav` (55px) and `#drawer` (50px). At a window height of, say 700px, that leaves 70px - which is a whole lot less then 65+55+50=170px.

You'd need a height of exactly 10x170=1700px for your layout to work - or in other words: never mix pixels and percentages...

Comment: What layout would you suggest so that the headers and footers are fixed height in the correct position and #mainsection fills the rest of the space?